# Increasing sequence of compacts of $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I first recall a definition:

Let $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A sequence $(K_n)$ of compact subsets of $\Omega$ is said to be *exhaustive* if we have:
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,K_n\subset\mathring{K_{n+1}}$$ and
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K_n=\Omega$$
We can show that for each open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, there exist exhaustive sequences of compacts, and that if $(K_n)$ is such a sequence, then for any compact $K\subset\Omega$, $K$ is a subset of one of the $K_n$.

---

Now here's my problem:

I take $n=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$. I want to find an increasing sequence of compacts $(K_n)$ whose union is $(0,1)$ and a compact $K\subset (0,1)$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $K\not\subset K_n$.

$(K_n)$ is increasing so we have $K_n\subset K_{n+1}$ for all $n$, but we can't have $K_n\subset\mathring{K_{n+1}}$ for all $n$, otherwise the sequence would be exhaustive and $K$ wouldn't exist. So I think there is something to do with the boundaries of the compacts, but I can't figure out what.

The first thing I thought of was
$$K_n=\left[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$$ but it's exhaustive...

Comment: Pick your favorite positive sequence $(x_n)$ decreasing to zero with $x_1<\frac14$ and your favorite $x$ in the interval $(2x_1,1-2x_1)$, and consider $$K_n=[x_n,x-x_n]\cup\{x\}\cup[x+x_n,1-x_n].$$ Finding a suitable $K$ should be doable...

Comment: Nice one, @Did. Easily beats my answer; you should make it one.

Comment: $x_n=\frac{1}{n+4}$, $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $K$ is some $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ for example?

Comment: @Augustin Precisely.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity of the construction, consider $(-1,1)$.

Let $K = \{0\} \cup \{\frac1{n+1}: n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Define $K_n$ as: $$K_n = \left[-\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n}{n+1}\right] \setminus \bigcup_{k = n}^\infty \left(\frac1{4k+3},\frac1{4k+1}\right)$$

Then it is manifest that $K_n$ is increasing and its union is $(-1,1)$. However, for each $n$, $\dfrac1{4n+2} \in K$, but $\dfrac1{4n+2} \notin K_n$. Hence $K \not\subset K_n$.

Comment: $K_n = \left[-\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n}{n+1}\right] \setminus \bigcup_{k = n}^\infty \left(\frac1{4k+3},\frac1{4k+1}\right)$, right?I think I got it, I just have to convince myself that the union is $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @Augustin Yes, sorry for my sloppiness.

Answer (score 1):

Next try ;-)

Choose $0< a < b < c < d$ and let $K_1 = [a,b]\cup[c,d]$

Choose exhaustive sequnces $L_i, M_i, N_i$ of $(0, a), (b,c)$ and $(d,1)$ respectively, then let $K_i= K_1 \cup L_i \cup M_i \cup N_i$ 
The union of the $K_i$ will cover $(0,1)$, but the interval $[b,c]$ will not be contained in any finite $K_i,$ because otherwise $(b,c)$ would be contained in a finite number of the $M_i$.

Comment: For any $i$, there exists $x\in (b,c)\setminus M_i$. Then $x\in [b,c]$ but $x\not\in K_i$. So $[b,c]\not\subset K_i$. Is this the right conclusion?

Comment: @Augustin yes, that's the right conclusion